# Can't Leverage Browser on a few items

Tags: javascript, caching

I tried all different commands in the .htaccess and for some reason a few items won't cache and it slows down my site. Here is an example of one of them:

```
    # TN - START EXPIRES CACHING #
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
    ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
    # TN - END EXPIRES CACHING #
    # TN - BEGIN Cache-Control Headers
    <ifModule mod_headers.c>
    <filesMatch "\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "public"
    </filesMatch>   
    <filesMatch "\.(css)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "public"
    </filesMatch>   
    <filesMatch "\.(js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "private"
    </filesMatch>   
    <filesMatch "\.(x?html?|php)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "private, must-revalidate"
    </filesMatch>   
    </ifModule>   
    # TN - END Cache-Control Headers
    # TN - BEGIN Turn ETags Off
    FileETag None
    # TN - END Turn ETags Off
```

But when I run a speed test I still get:

```
https://cdn.rlets.com/capture_static/mms/capture.js (expiration not specified)
https://cdn.rlets.com/capture_static/mms/mms.js (expiration not specified)
https://mywebsite.ico (expiration not specified)
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=bwpRecaptchaCallback&render=explicit (5 minutes)
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/webworker.js?hl=en&v=v1531759913576 (5 minutes)
https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js (2 hours)
```

I    set the javascript expire so why is there still JS showing up? Any   idea  how to fix these it's really slowing my site down? Thanks

Comment: An even better way to speed up your site is to go through and delete things you don't need.

Answer (score 0):

You can only set the caching headers for script files that you control.  These scripts are on separate servers, so those servers are setting their own caching policies.

Also - `ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"` - this doesn't seem like a good idea.  If you update one of your site's pages, then it could be up to a month before visitors see the new content.